# Perl Printing an Array

Tags: perl

I have a code something like this:

```
@VAR1 = {
      'ID' => '1',
      'Name' => '"ABC"'
    },
    {
      'ID' => '2',
      'Name' => '"EFG"'
    };
```

I am using this as below:

```
my @Var2 = ({
              'A' => "B",
              'C' => "D",
              'E' => \@Var1
              },
              {
              'A1' => "B1",
              'C1' => "D1",
              'E' => \@Var1
              });
```

So when I do a Dumper on AVar2, it is something like:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'A' => 'B',
      'C' => 'D',
      'E' => [
                  {
                    'ID' => '1',
                    'Name' => '"ABC"'
                  },
                  {
                    'ID' => '2',
                    'Name' => '"EFG"'
                  };
             ]
    };


$VAR2 = { 'A' => 'B',
      'C' => 'D',
      'E' => $VAR1->{'E'}
    };
```

Why is this not printing in the second case.Although it prints on the first place?

Comment: Can you show how you call `Dumper` and `@Var2` ?

Comment: what's happens when you do `print Dumper \@Var2` ?

Comment: 'E' => $VAR1->[0]{'E'}

Answer (score 1):

http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html

> Data::Dumper will catalog all references encountered while dumping the values. Cross-references (in the form of names of substructures in perl syntax) will be inserted at all possible points, preserving any structural interdependencies in the original set of values. Structure traversal is depth-first, and proceeds in order from the first supplied value to the last.

You can disable that :

> $Data::Dumper::Deepcopy or $OBJ->Deepcopy([NEWVAL])
>   Can be set to a boolean value to enable deep copies of structures. Cross-referencing will then only be done when absolutely essential (i.e., to break reference cycles). Default is 0.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are doing

```
print(Dumper(@Var2));
```

when the proper usage is

```
local $Data::Dumper::Purity = 1;
print(Dumper(\@Var2));
```

This outputs

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'A' => 'B',
            'C' => 'D',
            'E' => [
                     {
                       'ID' => '1',
                       'Name' => '"ABC"'
                     },
                     {
                       'ID' => '2',
                       'Name' => '"EFG"'
                     }
                   ]
          },
          {
            'A1' => 'B1',
            'E' => [],
            'C1' => 'D1'
          }
        ];
$VAR1->[1]{'E'} = $VAR1->[0]{'E'};
```

The above does accurately rebuild your data structure. You seem to expect

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'A' => 'B',
            'C' => 'D',
            'E' => [
                     {
                       'ID' => '1',
                       'Name' => '"ABC"'
                     },
                     {
                       'ID' => '2',
                       'Name' => '"EFG"'
                     }
                   ]
          },
          {
            'A1' => 'B1',
            'E' => [
                     {
                       'ID' => '1',
                       'Name' => '"ABC"'
                     },
                     {
                       'ID' => '2',
                       'Name' => '"EFG"'
                     }
                   ],
            'C1' => 'D1'
          }
        ];
```

But that's not equivalent to what you have. In your original structure,

- `$Var2[0]{E}` and `$Var2[1]{E}` are both references to the same array
- `$Var2[0]{E}[0]` and `$Var2[1]{E}[0]` are both references to the same hash
- `$Var2[0]{E}[1]` and `$Var2[1]{E}[1]` are both references to the same hash

In your expected output,

- `$Var2[0]{E}` and `$Var2[1]{E}` are references to different arrays
- `$Var2[0]{E}[0]` and `$Var2[1]{E}[0]` are references to different hashes
- `$Var2[0]{E}[1]` and `$Var2[1]{E}[1]` are references to different hashes

You can get the output you want using

```
local $Data::Dumper::Deepcopy = 1;
```

But if you do, your dumped data structure will be different than your actual data structure.